# CloudFront Multi Origin + Multi S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

bucket_01
=> web site hosting

bucket_02
=> public but no web site hosting

I put index.html to bucket_01

I created one distribution of CloudFront and two origins.

one origin is bucket_01.
the other one is bucket_02.

`img/test01.png` is on bucket_01 and cached from CloudFront
but `https://bucket_02.amazonaws.com/images/test02.png` is not cached from cloud front.

How `https://bucket_02.amazonaws.com/images/test02.png` can be cached from CloudFront?

```
 <div>
    <p>origin 1</p>
    <img src="img/test01.png">
    <p>origin 2</p>
    <img src="https://bucket_02.amazonaws.com/images/test02.png"
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Caching in CloudFront is managed under `Behavior` functionality. If you have 2 origins and want to mange separate caching then you need 2 separate paths. Each path with different (or no) caching.

In your case `img/*` belongs to origin 1 (bucket_01). And `images/*` belongs to bucket_02 (origin 2).

As a solution; you can either put everything under `Default` behaviour or create 2 behaviours based on 2 paths (img & images).

Open the Behaviour functionality and add cache values as shown below.

[image: CloudFront Cache in Bheviour]